# How to validate laravel array with custom request?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, laravel

How to validate with custom request, my request with an array key

```
$request = [
  'link_inc_characteristic_id' => $inc_char_id[$i],
  'value' => $value[$i],
  'created_by' => $created_by,
  'last_updated_by' => $last_updated_by,
];

$this->validate($request, [
   'value['.$i.']' => 'max:30'
]);

$linkIncCharacteristicValue = LinkIncCharacteristicValue::create($request);
return Response::json($linkIncCharacteristicValue);
```

[EDIT] [CODE UPDATED]
display error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given,

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Validation does not work and no error..... input value automatic cut on database field length, no error from validation..

Comment: I just renewed code.. and getting error

Comment: I think, you store not array to $request['value'] = $value[$i]
but you trying validate 'value['.$i.']' => 'max:30',
if you need validate array you must type 'value.*' => 'max:30'

Comment: this my submitted data on console, with ajax ;

`value[18] 
value[19] 
value[20] 
value[5] asasasaasshgafshgafshgafshgafsfafsasasasa
value[7] 
value[8] 
value[9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because I am putting the validation inside loop and not use `*` character to validate an array

```
...
for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
   ...
   $this->validate($request, [
      'value['.$i.']' => 'max:30'
   ]);
   ...
   // save etc
}
```

right code, put validation before loop, and use * character for array validation :

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'value.*' => 'max:30'
]);
...
for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
   // save etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Controller::validate()` is not a generic validation method, it validates **requests**. For this use case, simply use the validator directly:

```
Validator::make($data, ['value' => 'max:30']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what’s wrong:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given

So pass the `Request` instance to the `validate()` method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'value.*' => 'max:30',
    ]);
}
```

Check out the following resources:

- https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#validation-quickstart
- https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#validating-arrays